# Silverlight Arg_COMException

Tags: silverlight, debugging, exception, wsod

Our team has developed Silverilght 4 application. But we fall into problem with sporadic defect which causes Arg_COMException to be thrown. Here is stack trace for this error:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60531.0&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_COMException
in MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
in MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_ArrangeOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size finalSize)
in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)

There is no silverlight plugin crash after such error. But SL screen is disappear and you can you see host page (usually blank).

We cannot catch this exception in managed code. We don't know how to reproduce this bug, but it appears at least once a day (usually more).

Our application consists of wcf services, animations, timers and so on.
We do have a lot of custom controls based on UIElement.

We are looking for your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the client machine has the latest SL4 runtime installed?  Has it got a beta SL5 runtime installed?

Comment: We have several test environments. We tested on version 4.0.60531.0 and 4.0.60831.0 with the same result. At version 5 is not yet tested.